# Filtering Children of the “uncategorized” Category out of the Loop?

Tags: categories

I have some utility categories that are only used by my theme. To help separate these categories I place them all as children of uncategorized.

How can I make sure that any call to wp_list_categories() excludes the child categories under "uncategorized" cat_id = 1?

I want this to work even if the call wp_list_categories() comes from a third party plugin that I don't control.

Perhaps a filter I can place in functions.php that intercepts any call for the wp_list_categories() function to attach the exlude_tree = '1' to the arguments.

For example, in my own categories plugin widget, I use this...

```
    <ul>
<?php
    $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
    $cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;
    wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Scott B**:

**UPDATE FROM PRIOR ANSWER**: Due you my evidently poor reading comprehension skills(!) where I missed the requirement to filter out children (Thanks *@Adam BlackStrom* for calling attention to my oversight) I've modified the code provided.

---

I think you want to use the `list_terms_exclusions` filter hook. Add this to your plugin (or others needing the same add to the bottom of your theme's `functions.php` file):

```
function my_list_terms_exclusions($exclusions,$args) {
  $children = implode(',',get_term_children(1,'category'));
  $children = (empty($children) ? '' : ",$children");
  return $exclusions . " AND (t.term_id NOT IN (1{$children}))";
}
```

Of course the above will affect all category listings which you might not want so you might need to inspect the values in the `$args` array or more likely inspect other global state to only add the filter criteria only in the context(s) in which you need it.

If you have specifics we of where you need help limiting please ask a follow up question so we can help.

P.S. Also, I agree with Adam. If possible use a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Ah, I missed that filter as I was reading through `get_terms()`! Maybe that combined with `get_term_children()` is the answer; I assume your code will still return children of "Uncategorized."

Comment: @Adam: Not sure how to answer so I'll just explain. I took @Scott B's code and ran with `echo`+`exit` statements to output the value of `$exclusions`. It was `" AND ( t.term_id <> 1 )"` and without `$cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;` it was blank which told me to have the filter add it in. Reading the code it seemed to be excluding anything that is categorized with `cat=1`. I didn't explore or test beyond that.

Comment: Right, it does correctly exclude term_id 1 ("Uncategorized") but will still show child categories. To work for Scott, you would also need to explicitly exclude all the child categories of "Uncategorized."

Comment: @Adam - I may be missing something but reading @Scott B's comments it seems that he only needs to exclude the parent because he states. Maybe he'll help us and clarify which of these solutions addresses his specific use-case.

Comment: In his question he asks, "How can I make sure that any call to wp_list_categories() excludes the child categories under 'uncategorized' cat_id = 1?"

Comment: @Adam. Wow, my bad. Clearly I rate "F" for my reading comprehension for that one. Let me look at it again...

Comment: @Mike - Thanks very much. This works perfectly, I've added an "if(!defined('WP_ADMIN')) {" check so that the categories are not excluded in the admin.

Comment: @Mike - Would it be possible to add something to keep the description field from being written to the title tags of the list items? I'm using "$cat_args['use_desc_for_title'] = 0" in my wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));

Comment: @Scott B - Not sure I'm following you, but have you tried the `'category_description'` hook?

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer based on OP comments:

There isn't a filter or hook you can use with `wp_list_categories`, but there *is* a filter on the `get_categories` function that it calls.

The `get_categories` function makes this call:

```
$taxonomy = apply_filters( 'get_categories_taxonomy', $args['taxonomy'], $args );
```

The `$args` variable in this case is an array constructed originally from `wp_list_categories` and then merged with `'taxonomy' => 'category'`.  So you should be able to add a filter here to always set `exclude_tree='1'`.

Just be sure to specify that your function takes two parameters:

```
function exclude_children($taxonomy, $args) {
    $args['exclude_tree'] => '1';
}

add_filter('get_categories_taxonomy', 'exclude_children', 10, 2);
```

Comment: HI EAMann, thanks for the quick response. I can exclude categories by passing a parent id without a problem, now. See my code above, the exclude_tree argument does just that. However, that's MY own plugin, so I have that luxury. I'm trying to (continued...)

Comment: ...force that exclusion in my theme files so that the category is always excluded from any call to wp_list_categories...

Comment: *@EAMann*: as you've probably figured out you'd have to pass `$args` by reference (i.e. using `&$args`) for the above code to work, except WordPress passed a value when it runs `apply_filter()` so you can't do that, unfortunately.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel ... yeah, that's where I'm stuck at with this solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to modify `get_terms()` to exclude "Uncategorized" and any children:

```
// modify the term list to exclude "Uncategorized" and any children
function no_uncategorized( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    global $my_excluded_categories;

    $uncategorized = term_exists( 'Uncategorized', 'category' );

    $my_excluded_categories = get_term_children( $uncategorized['term_id'], 'category' );
    $my_excluded_categories[] = $uncategorized['term_id'];

    $terms = array_filter( $terms, 'no_uncategorized_filter' );

    return $terms;
}

// used by array_filter to exclude anything in the excluded categories
function no_uncategorized_filter( $category ) {
    global $my_excluded_categories;
    return !in_array( $category->term_id, $my_excluded_categories );
}

// only done during template_redirect (the public-facing site)
function do_template_redirect() {
    add_filter( 'get_terms', 'no_uncategorized', 10, 3 );
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'do_template_redirect' );
```

I think the real answer, though, is **don't use categories**, instead **[register your own taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)**. No more hidden categories, just a private taxonomy that isn't picked up by `wp_list_categories()`.

Comment: Adam, you are correct. Had I known about how to create my own taxonomies, it would have been the way to go. As it is, utilizing the built in categories system was a quick and easy way to do it, with minimal side effects :) I'll be checking out your suggestion for an upgrade of my theme...